# Setting up a WPF DataGrid with 2 Fixed and n Variable columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, dynamic-columns

I have 2 columns that are fixed, a checkbox and a date column.  The rest of the columns can vary in the number of columns but the data in these columns are all the same info (name, checkbox, text, button)

Can I use a single DataGrid to do this through a template or do I have to have 1 DataGrid for the fixed columns and another DataGrid for the rest of the columns?

Also how do I template for an unknown number of columns?

My data structure is multiple readings vertically and for a single reading, I have an IsSelected flag and the DateTaken then I have a List and this can be 1-20 columns of them.  All Readings will have the same number of Vitals.

```
Reading 1>    IsSelected | DateTaken | Vital | Vital | Vital...     
Reading 2>    IsSelected | DateTaken | Vital | Vital | Vital...     

   98.6 F
    ORAL

where each vital is two rows in a cell: Measurement                  
                                        Qualifiers
```

This is the column definition for the Vitals

```
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="Vitals">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vital.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Button Content="{Binding Vital.Unit}" Margin="1" Click="Unit_Click" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="120" Margin="3">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HideValues, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInverter}}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="1" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}"  Margin="3,1" />
                                </StackPanel>

                                <CheckBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding HideValues}" Height="15" Width="15" ToolTip="Select to exclude value" DataContext="{Binding}"
                                           BorderThickness="1" Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="White"
                                           Visibility="{Binding HideCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInverter}}" Template="{StaticResource VitalCheckBox}" />

                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HideValues, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInverter}}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qualifiers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding}"
                                               ToolTip="{Binding Qualifiers}" Width="101" />

                                    <Button    Name="SelectQualifier" Content="..." FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding SelectQualifiersCommand}" DataContext="{Binding}"
                                               ToolTip="Assign qualifiers" Visibility="{Binding HideQualBtn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInverter}}"
                                               Padding="2,0" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I would like to do this in the XAML and not in the code-behind.  I think it is doable but I just have not found a way yet...

Comment: You cannot do this completely without some code behind.  For starters autogenerate columns wants to generate all the columns.  To stop generation of your fixed columns, then you need to declare an AutoGeneratingColumn event to cancel these columns.  Also I am confused by the shape of your data model.  I think you need to provide some more code before anyone can give you a useful answer.

Comment: Yes you can do that, in your last column of your main datagrid, use a templatecolumn with a datagrid to show your variable columns.